# How should I run long-running or recurring taks in a self-hosted .net core mvc application?

Tags: c#, .net-core

What is the best practice for running additional continuous tasks(e.g a timer) in .net core mvc application (since there is no `Application_start` event). Should i place it in the `Main` method or somewhere else?

It's a self-hosted app.

Comment: Is it good enough for you to check what tasks are due to be run at the end of serving each page?  (With caching to save hitting the database too often.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would create it a separate Console App and schedule a window task using Task Scheduler to execute this app as needed, this is the case if you are deploying in a VM, if you are deploying to Azure, then it will be a Web Job.

I will do my best to keep away any long running processes from MVC

Comment: This is true when using IIS or Azure hosting. .NET Core allow self-hosted application though, which *are* console applications. In this case the warnings about long-running tasks don't apply in the same way. A common scenario will be to run on Linux, so the equivalent task scheduler would be cron

Comment: I agree with you, but even if it was self-hosted, you can't guarantee what will happen if there were some threads or Process objects running inside the self-hosted App, and you will have to implement the logic for scheduling and accommodate for failures

Comment: Ok, i got it. But if we don't want to complicate deployment process(we alreadry have a couple of applications, and we dont want to create another one). What can you recommend?

Comment: I tried Including the timer before in applications and to be honest, the headache generated was too way higher than using a scheduler, you can create a simple PowerShell script to handle the creation of the Windows Scheduler and make it point to the EXE of the console App and that is it.